# 'Footer' style bar at top of web page isn't working. CSS & HTML

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

http://biggerbyte.net/testwebsite/test.html

There is a hosted version of the website

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 .footer {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.footer a {
  color: white;
}
.footer a:hover {
  color: #E8DE4D;
}
.background-image {
  background-image: url("http://garanthomas.me/images/dsc00813-2.jpg?crc=4106647053");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
.content-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #4A4A4A;
  width: 450px;
  opacity: 0.65;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Sans, DejaVu Sans, Verdana, " sans-serif";
  font-size: 90;
  color: white;
}
.content-box p {
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Sans, DejaVu Sans, Verdana, " sans-serif";
  font-size: 90;
  color: white;
}
.content-box h1 {
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Sans, DejaVu Sans, Verdana, " sans-serif";
  font-size: 90;
  color: white;
}
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.cb-slideshow:after {
  content: '';
  background: transparent url(../images/patterrn.png) repeat top left;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.cb-slideshow li span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.cb-slideshow li div {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 {
  font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
  background-image: url(images/1.jpg)
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url(images/3.jpg);
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
  background-image: url(images/2.jpg);
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
  background-image: url(images/4.jpg);
  animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
  background-image: url(images/5.jpg);
  animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
  background-image: url(images/6.jpg);
  animation-delay: 30s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div {
  animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div {
  animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div {
  animation-delay: 30s;
}
@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 0.5
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 0.5
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span {
  opacity: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
  .cb-slideshow li div h3 {
    font-size: 140px
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .cb-slideshow li div h3 {
    font-size: 80px
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>index</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="footer">©2016 Garan Thomas - <a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>.</div>

  <ul class="cb-slideshow">
    <li>
      <span>Image 01</span>
      <div>
        <h3>Brecon</h3>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span>Image 03</span>
      <div>
        <h3>Swansea</h3>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li><span>Image 02</span>
      <div>
        <h3>Brecon</h3>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span>Image 04</span>
      <div>
        <h3>Neath</h3>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span>Image 05</span>
      <div>
        <h3>Brecon Beacons</h3>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span>Image 06</span>
      <div>
        <h3>Rhigos</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <center>

    <div class="content-box">
      <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
      <p>Welcome to my photography website. Here you can find my photography work, website work and other things I decide to put up.</p>
    </div>

  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Above is the code I used. The code is messy and alot of it is copied from a small guide I followed. I'm still learning this type of code so please excuse any mistakes. What I found was without the .footer bar at the top of my web page I found a white gap which is essentially a bare website where you can see anything written there and so on. I couldn't find a way to solve this so I thought I'd add a little footer style bar along the top of the website where I'd put navigation there down the line but for now I stole the footer from another website and quickly edited it to be at the top of the web page. I think it looks quite nice but I noticed that the hyperlink I had and the text inside the bar cannot be highlighted, as if something is above it blocking it on the web page like a layer in photoshop for example. Can anyone help me fix this? tell me what's wrong or anything I've done in my code that I should avoid in future? or any suggestions for the website? I'm more than welcome to any response.

Thank you for the time and answers.

Comment: If you're just starting out, you may want to add a this css before you start typing your own css. It will remove many styles that are browser-specific (and with that I mean, each browser has a different style): http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to resolve this without placing the bar there, the issue causing the white space at the top is that your entire page content is within an `unordered list`. By default, browsers will apply a top margin to `unordered lists`, so all you would have to do is override that like so:

```
ul.cb-slideshow {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

If you want to keep the bar at the top, the issue there is that the `z-index` of the "footer" bar is lower than that of the `unordered list`. You can resolve that by setting the z-index of the footer:

```
.footer {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 1; /* Make sure footer is above ul */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `z-index: 1;` to the `.footer` in the CSS. However, you should name it something else than `footer`...

Answer (score 0):

For your footer, give it a `z-index` higher than anything else to keep it on top and set the `bottom` to 0. Also, in the HTML, put it at the end of the body. 
So your final css for the footer becomes.

```
.footer {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

And for the whitespace on top, it's your unordered list automatically getting a margin-top from the browser, use this:

```
ul.cb-slideshow {
margin-top: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n86sf83y/)

Comment: He uses `footer`, but it's really a header. No need to put it at the bottom.

Comment: @Feathercrown Well, this is not semantic at all. So I don't recommend it to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the answers. I fixed it by adding a Z-Index of a higher number than my slideshow and I also got rid of the silly gap that was there by using the

```
ul.cb-slideshow {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try and add footer to the bottom after

```
</center>

<footer class="footer">©2016 Garan Thomas - <a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>.</footer>
```

Comment: That's not what he was looking for.